# How to handle pipelines in tensorflow vs sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm just started studying deep learning and I'm trying to implement pipelines for a better data flow.
I come from a scikit learn background where pipelines are pretty straight forward:

```
logreg = Pipeline(
[('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
 ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= 50))]
```

)

Just state your transformations and attach a model to fit at the end. On the other side, with Tensorflow's tf.data it's much more cumbersome:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))

def preprocess(x, y):
    # Standard scaling
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[0])
    x = (x - mean) / tf.sqrt(variance)
    return x, y

batch_size = 32
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess).batch(batch_size)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(8,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, my problem lies specifically with how this pipeline is implemented (not with the model), since you are supposed to keep adding methods to the dataset to complete the pipeline.
I know it's possible to combine tensorflow models into sklearn pipelines via a keras wrapper:

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=32))
])
```

So now I'm wondering on what are the best practices as to code readability, performance, optimization, etc. As far as I know Tensorflow is very optimized so i don't know what the impact would be if i used sklearn api, but then again I think sklearn pipelines have better functionalities, as well as ease of ensembling with other machine learning models.
So, should I just stick with tf.data, or is combining sklearn with tensorflow a good alternative?